# .NET Component for Excel 2003 spreadsheet generation using templates for formatting

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel

The problem my application is trying to solve is this:

Currently, several stored procedures are run, the data is manually copied out of the SQL results into a blank spreadsheet, and reporting analysts format the data. This process has been deemed too long and costly.

The ideal solution (in my mind) is a .NET application with a component that can take a stored procedure result and write it to a specific cell range in a worksheet template (maintaining template formatting) and then I can just collate the results into workbooks in the .NET application.

Are there any such applications out there? Even better, does anyone have any better solutions?

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use to set the data

get the data in the form of

```
object[,] excelSpreadsheetData
```

then apply the data by setting

```
public void SetWorksheetData(long rowCount, long columnCount, object[,] excelSpreadsheetData, int startingRow, int startingCol, Worksheet worksheet)
        {
            if (rowCount == 0 || columnCount == 0) return;
            //set the region data.
            object m_objOpt = Missing.Value;
            Range cellRange = worksheet.get_Range(ExcelGeneratorUtils.ExcelColumnFromNumber(startingCol) + startingRow, m_objOpt);
            cellRange = cellRange.get_Resize(rowCount, columnCount);
            cellRange.set_Value(m_objOpt, excelSpreadsheetData);
        }
```

This should keep the template formatting, and sets the data in one go, much faster than setting it cell, by cell.

Hope that helps

Comment: Where can you access the ExcelGeneratorUtils to do the Column from Number transformation?

Comment: This was a custom function. I will be able to give you an example a bit later, K X-)

Comment: Hey, i found my old post, you can find the convertion function here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837155/fastest-function-to-generate-excel-column-letters-in-c

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. Another thing I'm getting mildly stuck on is the object[,] - what type is this?

Comment: Tha would just be an 2 dimentional object array, the size of the rowsXcels to set in the spreadsheet. What makes this faster is, that the object array is produced before the set occurs, then setting the data to excel happens once, instead of cell by cell. I will look for an example here on how i did that...

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Excel Automation through interop.  I have done this on occasion when the desired output is Excel.  Its surprisingly quick, you have to be careful though to clean up after yourself and not leave instances of Excel running.  Here is a brief sample.

```
        using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        Excel.ApplicationClass _Excel;
        Excel.Workbook WB;
        Excel.Worksheet WS;


        _Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        WB = _Excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

        WS = (Excel.Worksheet)WB.Worksheets[1]; 
        WS.Name = "Test";

         try
        {

            int row;
            int col;

            WS.Cells[++row, col] = "COL1";
            WS.Cells[row, ++col] = "COL2";

            WS.get_Range("A1", "A2").Font.Bold = true;
            WS.get_Range("A1", "A2").HorizontalAlignment                     =Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

            WS.Cells[++row, col] = "Customer";
            WS.Cells[++row, col] = "Expenses" 

            WS.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;


            WS.Columns.AutoFit();
            WS.Rows.AutoFit();

            WS.Activate();
           _Excel.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            _Excel.Quit();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();



            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WS);


            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(WB);

            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_Excel);


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will let you open Excel workbooks, plug in values and save the workbook.

You can see Excel Reporting (i.e., export to Excel) samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964777/creating-an-excel-spreadsheetml-in-code-without-excel) I asked for something similar. The difference is that I want something to generate an XML file that's interpreted by Excel as a spreadsheet. If you could send the data to an XML file, then transform the XML to SpreadsheetML, then this might solve your problem.
SpreadsheetXM does have a few limitations, though. It won't require Excel to be installed and the transformation can be real fast. And if you use Excel 2007 then there's a second XML format that you could use, the [Microsoft Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) format.
Basically, it's slow because I suspect that your current code is interacting with Excel through COM.

Comment: Ah crap, I forgot to mention that I'm restricted to Excel 2003. Updating question...

Comment: I think the biggest issue with this is that your solution doesn't seem to allow me to persist formatting - is there any way to apply templated formatting to a SpreadsheetML document?

Comment: SpreadsheetML does allow some simple formatting but not all of the formatting you'd like. The best way to see what it can and cannot do is by creating a spreadsheet and then exporting this to a SpreadsheetML XML file. (File/Save as/XML Spreadsheet.) Re-open this XML spreadsheet and see what's left of your formatting. If it's still okay, use this XML as basis for your stylesheet to convert the XML to spreadsheet...