# C# Accessing Excel Worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, connection-string

Is this the correct way to access a MS Office Excel 2007 file?

```
        String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
    "Data Source=" + file_path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
```

If so, how do I access a certain worksheet and insert rows?  Links are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an article on codeproject - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx - which should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Connection string

```
  connectionString = @"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1""";
```

reading data

```
 excelConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        excelConnection.Open();
        dbSchema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        firstSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" + firstSheetName + "]";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, excelConnection);
        da.Fill(dt);
```

writing data see [Excel  Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405431/net-component-for-excel-2003-spreadsheet-generation-using-templates-for-formatti/1405533#1405533) this uses automation though.  It may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28office.11%29.aspx) (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel):

Here's a snippet of some code:

```
object missing = (object) Type.Missing;

Application app = new Application();

Workbooks books = app.Workbooks;

Workbook book = books.Open("somefile.xls", missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
            missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
```

It's got some weirdnesses (like those "missing" parameters) but it works pretty smoothly. If you take this approach, be careful that the EXCEL.exe process doesn't get orphaned.